# Reference error when unit testing VUE3 component with jest typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, ts-jest

I am new to vue and writing unit tests.
I am stuck on reference error even though my tests are passed.
My current test file:

```js
    require('isomorphic-fetch');
    import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
    import WeatherWidget from '@/components/WeatherWidget.vue';

    describe('WeatherWidget.vue', () => {
       it('renders', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(WeatherWidget, {
            props: {
                lat: 41.3888,
                lon: 2.1667,
            },
        });
     });
```

and having error like:
[image]

The error reference it is showing is a separate file in which i m exporting a function which returns path to image (dynamic image name).

My script Component.vue:

```js
<script lang="ts">
// Built-in Imports
import { computed, defineComponent, onBeforeMount, ref } from "vue";

// 3rd Party Import
import { useLoading } from 'vue-loading-overlay'

// Custom Utils and Models Imports
import { Weather, WeatherSummary } from "@/models/Weather";
import { windDirection } from "@/utils/wind-direction";
import { getCountryByCode } from "@/utils/countries-list";
import { getIconPath } from "@/utils/fetch-weather-icon"

// Component Import
import MiniForecastWidget from "./MiniForecastWidget.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props) {

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ------------------------- Initializing variables -------------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    const $loading = useLoading();

    const weatherAPI = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lon=${props.lon}&lat=${props.lat}&units=metric&exclude=minutely,hourly&appid=${process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY}`;
    const geoCodeAPI = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/reverse?lon=${props.lon}&lat=${props.lat}&limit=1&appid=${process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY}`;

    // TODO: Dummy data | to be removed later
    let dummyData: Weather = {
      city: "---",
      country: "---",
      weatherId: 800,
      weatherMain: "Clear",
      weatherIcon: "01d",
      weatherDescription: "clear",
      temperature: 0,
      date: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      uvi: 0,
      windSpeed: 0,
      windDeg: 0,
    };

    const currentWeather = ref<Weather>(dummyData);
    const weatherData = ref<WeatherSummary[]>([]);
    const location = ref<{ city: string, country: string }>({
      city: "",
      country: "-",
    });

    const rain = ref(false)

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ---------------------------- Custom Functions ----------------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Fetching location with latitude and longitude
    const reverseGeocode = async () => {
      await fetch(geoCodeAPI)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          const country = getCountryByCode(res[0]?.country);
          currentWeather.value.country = country;
          location.value = {
            city: res[0]?.name,
            country: country,
          };
        });
    };

    // Fetches weather data from the Open Weather API
    const fetchWeatherForecast = async () => {
      const loader = $loading.show({
        color: '#0668C2',
      });
      const response = await fetch(weatherAPI);
      const resp = await response.json();

      // Manually mapping response to our model
      if (resp.current) {
        const mappedData: Weather = {
          weatherId: resp.current.weather[0].id,
          weatherMain: resp.current.weather[0].main,
          weatherIcon: resp.current.weather[0].icon,
          weatherDescription: resp.current.weather[0].description,
          temperature: resp.current.temp,
          date: resp.current.dt,
          humidity: resp.current.humidity,
          uvi: resp.current.uvi,
          windSpeed: resp.current.wind_speed,
          windDeg: resp.current.wind_deg,
        }

        // Update current weather data
        currentWeather.value = mappedData;
      }


      if (resp.daily) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        const dailyForecastData: any[] = resp.daily;
        const mappedDailyForecast: WeatherSummary[] = [];

        // Manually mapping Daily forecast response array to our custom model array
        dailyForecastData.map((obj) => {
          const mappedDailyForecastData: WeatherSummary = {
            weatherMain: obj.weather[0].main,
            weatherId: obj.weather[0].id,
            weatherDescription: obj.weather[0].description,
            weatherIcon: obj.weather[0].icon,
            date: obj.dt,
            maxTemperature: Math.round(obj.temp.max),
            minTemperature: Math.round(obj.temp.min),
          }

          mappedDailyForecast.push(mappedDailyForecastData);
        });

        // Update forecast data with next five days only
        weatherData.value = mappedDailyForecast.slice(0, 6);

        loader.hide();
      }

    }

    const updateWeather = async () => {
      await fetchWeatherForecast();
    };

    const makeItRain = () => {
      rain.value = !rain.value;
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ---------------------------- Life Cycle Hook -----------------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      reverseGeocode();
      fetchWeatherForecast();
    });

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // -------------------- Computed Functions / Properties ---------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------


    const weatherIcon = computed(() => getIconPath(currentWeather.value.weatherId, currentWeather.value.weatherMain, currentWeather.value.weatherIcon)); // Get weather icon by invoking custom 'getWeatherIcon' util function
    const windDir = computed(() => windDirection(currentWeather.value.windDeg)); // Computing wind direction by invoking custom 'windDirection' util function
    const country = computed(() => getCountryByCode(currentWeather.value.country)); // Computing country by invoking custom 'getCountryByCode' util function
    const temperature = computed(() => Math.round(currentWeather.value.temperature)); // Round Temperature to nearest integer
    const windSpeed = computed(() => Math.round(currentWeather.value.windSpeed)); // Round Wind speed to nearest integer

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // --------------------------------- Return ---------------------------------
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return { location, weatherData, windDir, currentWeather, country, temperature, windSpeed, weatherIcon, updateWeather, makeItRain, rain };
  },
  components: {
    MiniForecastWidget
  },
  props: {
    lat: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    lon: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  }
});
</script>
```

=> `const weatherIcon = computed(() => getIconPath(currentWeather.value.weatherId, currentWeather.value.weatherMain, currentWeather.value.weatherIcon));`

While the `currentWeather` is the ref object which updates after component mounting.

Well my getIconPath function invokes two nested function in it:

```js
export function getIconPath(id: number, main: string, icon: string): string {
    let imgSrc = '';
    try {
        imgSrc = require(`@/assets/weather-widget-icons/ww-icon-${slugify(
            getWeatherIconName(id, main, icon)
        )}.svg`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            `Image '@/assets/weather-widget-icons/ww-icon-${slugify(
                getWeatherIconName(id, main, icon)
            )}.svg' not found!`
        );
    }
    return imgSrc;
}
```

Any help would be kind!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown how and where this function is called. Also, what is the point of this setTimeout?

Comment: Sorry i have update the question as i was trying with settimeout. Repalced with original test code.
Further more the function as you  can see `const weatherIcon` is what is called in `setup()' function

Comment: It's defined in setup, not called. As I mentioned, you'll need MCVE for this. The error means that weatherIcon is accessed asynchronously

Comment: @EstusFlask I have update code by adding my component script code. Please guide me to make if better. Next i need to test APIs with fetch api in same test file.

Comment: Network requests should always be mocked in unit tests. There are multiple ways to test this. The basic one is mock fetch to instantly return data you expect (there are many questions that address this) and await `flush-promises` before doing assertions.

Comment: @EstusFlask Oh great, this works amazingly just by adding `await flushPromises();`
Will testing network request work with flushing promise as i need to test if the response is 200